# Aligning images to the same height as video - CSS?

Tags: html, css

When I play video it may be landscape or portrait in orientation. I have 2 images imgfeatured1 and imgfeatured2 which appear left and right of the video respectively. I wish these images to adjust automatically to be the same height as the video being played.

```
<div id="streaming">
    <video playsinline ID="videoToPlay" poster="https://www.example.co.uk/files/images/videoPoster.jpg" runat="server"  autoplay preload class="videosize" controls>
        <source src="vid1.webm" type='video/webm;codecs="vp8, opus"'/> 
        <source src="vid2.mp4" type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
    <source src="video/video.mov" type="video/mov"></source>
    </video>

    <asp:Image ID="imgFeatured1" alt="Featured 1" imageUrl="https://www.example.co.uk/files/images/icons/featured1.png" class="videologo" runat="server" />

    <asp:Image ID="imgFeatured2" alt="Featured 2" imageUrl="https://www.example.co.uk/files/images/icons/featured2.png" class="videologoright" runat="server" />


</div>
```

CSS so far..

```
.videologo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
}

.videologoright {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want it static based on what is loaded on request you need to use javascript to get and set height on the images.

if you want the images to be on each side of the video you need to rearrange the html if you want to follow best practices.

---

### Javascript version:

*Get the height of the video and set that height to the image while width = auto*

```js
  var imageOne = document.getElementById("imgFeatured1");
  var imageTwo = document.getElementById("imgFeatured2");
  var vid = document.getElementById("videoToPlay");

  imageOne.style.height = vid.offsetHeight +"px";
  imageTwo.style.height = vid.offsetHeight + "px";
  
    console.log(vid.offsetHeight);
  console.log(imageTwo.style.height);
```

```css
#streaming {
  display: flex;
}

body {
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<body>



<div id="streaming">


  <img id="imgFeatured1" alt="Featured 1"
  src="https://betterstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/1-1-instagram-1024x1024.jpg"
  class="videologo" runat="server" />

  <div id="VidWrapper">
    <video playsinline id="videoToPlay" runat="server"  autoplay preload class="videosize" controls>
        <source src="vid1.webm" type='video/webm;codecs="vp8, opus"'/>
        <source src="vid2.mp4" type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
    <source src="video/video.mov" type="video/mov"></source>
    </video>
  </div>

    <img id="imgFeatured2" alt="Featured 2"
    src="https://betterstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/1-1-instagram-1024x1024.jpg"
     class="videologoright" runat="server" />


</div>

</body>
```

### CSS version

*Set img and video height to the same and automatic width*

```css
#streaming {
  display: flex;
}

body {
  background: #333;
}

img, video{
  
  height: 25vh;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>



<div id="streaming">


  <img id="imgFeatured1" alt="Featured 1"
  src="https://betterstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/1-1-instagram-1024x1024.jpg"
  class="videologo" runat="server" />

  <div id="VidWrapper">
    <video playsinline id="videoToPlay" runat="server"  autoplay preload class="videosize" controls>
        <source src="vid1.webm" type='video/webm;codecs="vp8, opus"'/>
        <source src="vid2.mp4" type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.4D401E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
    <source src="video/video.mov" type="video/mov"></source>
    </video>
  </div>

    <img id="imgFeatured2" alt="Featured 2"
    src="https://betterstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/1-1-instagram-1024x1024.jpg"
     class="videologoright" runat="server" />


</div>

</body>
```